# Multine Line label With Button

Tags: uilabel, tableview, swift4

How can i make a label multiline with a button next to it. Multiline works fine without the button. How should i set the trailing constant for button so that it moves along with the length of the label. Please see the screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Increasing the text moves my button away.

[image]

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the right constraint for the button with its superview. Beside, the size for the button is matter as well.

In your case, the code is really simple, let's say I write it using Snapkit autolayout kit:

```
attendeeLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
  make.top.centerY.bottom.equalToSuperview()
  make.left.equalToSuperview().offset(15)
}

cancelButton.snp.makeConstraints { make in
  make.top.equalTo(attendeeLabel.snp.top).offset(10)
  make.left.equalTo(attendeeLabel.snp.right).offset(5)
  make.right.lessThanOrEqualToSuperview() // <-- this will keep the button on the right side of the label, but will not exceed the superview
  make.width.height.equalTo(22) // <-- this is the size of the close button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow my steps

**Step1:**
Add a label and button.

**Step2:**
[image]

**Step3:**
[image]

**step4:**

[image]

**step5:**

[image]

Add other constraints according to your requirement.

It may helps you. Thank you.